# How to Make Li Boxes Line Up If They Have Variable Length Text In?

Tags: html, css

If I am using an unordered list with li items to display multiple boxes across the page, and onto multiple lines, and each box contains variable text length which pushes up the height of some of the boxes, how am I supposed to get all the boxes to line up across the page nicely, as they are currently variable height.

I can't specify a height because I don't know how much the text will push the box down, so how do I make all the boxes have the same height?

Here is an [example of the problem](http://webref.eu/test-uniform-box-size.htm). How do I make each row of li items have the same height?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you want, and - more importantly - share your [mcve] code that you're working with?

Comment: Try using CSS Grid. It automatically adjusts.

Comment: I don't want to use CSS grid, because I will be generating each li item out of a database. So, I just want a way to display multiple li items as boxes (i.e. each has a border on it), but make sure they all have the same box height. I was thinking maybe I have to detect the height using JavaScript?